# How to propperly publish an Android library?

Tags: java, android, maven

I made a library for reading and displaying csv files in the simplest way I could find, and it works great on my application, but once I try to publish it, on maven or jcenter, they accept what i did and show me a message telling me that everything is fine, but I can't use it with the gradle import in any way. I might be doing something wrong and I can't figure out in which step. Can someone please post here a updated step-by-step tutorial on how to publish libraries? Thanks!

Comment: can you tell us the packagename for the library?

Comment: com.mion.csvsimplereader, why?

Comment: was checking if its available on jcenter. it ain't.

Comment: oh, so I am doing something wrong before the gradle import, thanks!